# How to delete lines starting with certain strings

Tags: command-line, grep, sed, awk, youtube-dl

Is there a way to delete lines starting with certain strings.

I have this youtube-dl code

```
youtube-dl --extract-audio --audio-quality 0 --newline --audio-format mp3 https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL1C815DB73EC2678E
```

and its result is like this

```
[youtube:playlist] PL1C815DB73EC2678E: Downloading webpage
[download] Downloading playlist: Less than 1 minute
[youtube:playlist] playlist Less than 1 minute: Collected 4 video ids (downloading 4 of them)
[download] Downloading video 1 of 4
[youtube] KNLwsqzFfNg: Downloading webpage
[youtube] KNLwsqzFfNg: Extracting video information
[youtube] KNLwsqzFfNg: Downloading DASH manifest
[download] Destination: _1 min. - Amendes pour les particules du LHC-KNLwsqzFfNg.m4a

[download]   0.4% of 231.51KiB at  6.10KiB/s ETA 00:30
[download]   1.1% of 231.51KiB at 27.07KiB/s ETA 00:10
[download]   4.0% of 231.51KiB at 19.24KiB/s ETA 00:04
[download]   6.5% of 231.51KiB at 75.06KiB/s ETA 00:03
[download]  13.4% of 231.51KiB at 98.22KiB/s ETA 00:03
[download]  28.7% of 231.51KiB at 81.40KiB/s ETA 00:02
[download]  61.7% of 231.51KiB at 91.56KiB/s ETA 00:01
[download]  86.2% of 231.51KiB at 82.96KiB/s ETA 00:00
[download] 100.0% of 231.51KiB at 73.21KiB/s ETA 00:00
[download] 100% of 231.51KiB in 00:02
[ffmpeg] Correcting container in "_1 min. - Amendes pour les particules du LHC-KNLwsqzFfNg.m4a"
WARNING: Your copy of avconv is outdated, update avconv to version 10-0 or newer if you encounter any errors.
[avconv] Destination: _1 min. - Amendes pour les particules du LHC-KNLwsqzFfNg.mp3
WARNING: Your copy of avconv is outdated, update avconv to version 10-0 or newer if you encounter any errors.
Deleting original file _1 min. - Amendes pour les particules du LHC-KNLwsqzFfNg.m4a (pass -k to keep)
[download] Downloading video 2 of 4
[youtube] wTvXkMpJflk: Downloading webpage
[youtube] wTvXkMpJflk: Extracting video information
[youtube] wTvXkMpJflk: Downloading DASH manifest
```

I want to delete all lines starting with `[youtube]`, `[ffmpeg]`  and  `[avconv]` and get like this

```
[youtube:playlist] PL1C815DB73EC2678E: Downloading webpage
[download] Downloading playlist: Less than 1 minute
[youtube:playlist] playlist Less than 1 minute: Collected 4 video ids (downloading 4 of them)
[download] Downloading video 1 of 4
[download] Destination: _1 min. - Amendes pour les particules du LHC-KNLwsqzFfNg.m4a

[download]   0.4% of 231.51KiB at  6.10KiB/s ETA 00:30
[download]   1.1% of 231.51KiB at 27.07KiB/s ETA 00:10
[download]   4.0% of 231.51KiB at 19.24KiB/s ETA 00:04
[download]   6.5% of 231.51KiB at 75.06KiB/s ETA 00:03
[download]  13.4% of 231.51KiB at 98.22KiB/s ETA 00:03
[download]  28.7% of 231.51KiB at 81.40KiB/s ETA 00:02
[download]  61.7% of 231.51KiB at 91.56KiB/s ETA 00:01
[download]  86.2% of 231.51KiB at 82.96KiB/s ETA 00:00
[download] 100.0% of 231.51KiB at 73.21KiB/s ETA 00:00
[download] 100% of 231.51KiB in 00:02
WARNING: Your copy of avconv is outdated, update avconv to version 10-0 or newer if you encounter any errors.
WARNING: Your copy of avconv is outdated, update avconv to version 10-0 or newer if you encounter any errors.
Deleting original file _1 min. - Amendes pour les particules du LHC-KNLwsqzFfNg.m4a (pass -k to keep)
[download] Downloading video 2 of 4
etc..
etc..
.
.
```

i tried this method but its showing error and it only suppose to delete `[youtube]`

```
youtube-dl --extract-audio --audio-quality 0 --newline --audio-format mp3 https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL1C815DB73EC2678E | sed '^/[youtube]/ d'
```

Comment: Your pattern is wrong. It should be `sed '/^\[youtube\]/d'`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
sed -i '/\[youtube\]/d' /path/to/file
```

will delete lines, containing "[youtube]".

As one command you can combine patterns like

```
sed -i '/\[youtube\]\|\[ffmpeg\]\|\[avconv\]/d' /path/to/file
```

Or right from your command

```
youtube-dl --extract-audio --audio-quality 0 --newline --audio-format mp3 \
 https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL1C815DB73EC2678E | 
    sed '/\[youtube\]\|\[ffmpeg\]\|\[avconv\]/d' > output.txt
```

This will write the result to a file output.txt.

If you want to delete lines not just containing `[youtube]`, but starting with `[youtube]`, then add `^` to the pattern, like `sed '/^\[youtube\]/d'`.

But in your case it does not matter.

Comment: I tried this `sed -i '/\[youtube\]\|\[ffmpeg\]\|\[avconv\]/d'   youtube-dl --extract-audio --audio-quality 0 --newline --audio-format mp3 https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL1C815DB73EC2678E` and not working.  may be because its not a file and its a download link

Comment: Try with a file. It will work. Or you can do it right from the link using | pipe.

Comment: @potholiday I updated the answer

Comment: worked...  the edited one worked

Comment: and for me `> output.txt` is not necessary

Comment: how to delete `WARNING` line also  i tried like this \WARNING/d' but its not deleting.

Comment: @potholiday  You do not need to escape there, just `'/^WARNING/d'`

Comment: `sed '/\[youtube\]\|\[ffmpeg\]\|\[avconv\]|/^WARNING/d'` is showing error any idea whats happening

Comment: Do you see that `|` is also escaped with `\`?

Comment: showing this error `sed: -e expression #1, char 40: unknown command: `^'
`

Comment: There was a typo. `sed '/\[youtube\]\|\[ffmpeg\]\|\[avconv\]\|^WARNING/d'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24863/discussion-between-potholiday-and-pilot6).

Comment: it's really simple.  `sed -i '/youtube\|ffmpeg\|avconv\|WARNING/d'  file_name` you don't need multiple escapes

Answer (score 6):

I suggest using `grep -vE` like so:

`youtube-dl --extract-audio --audio-quality 0 --newline --audio-format mp3 https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL1C815DB73EC2678E | grep -vE '^\[(youtube|ffmpeg|avconv)\]'`

From `man grep`:

```
-v, --invert-match
              Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.  (-v
              is specified by POSIX.)



-E, --extended-regexp
              Interpret  PATTERN  as  an extended regular expression (ERE, see
              below).  (-E is specified by POSIX.)
```

The -E flag is used to avoid escaping square brackets with slashes. Without -E flag you have to escape the square brackets with a backslash, like so `grep -vE '\[youtube\]\|\[ffmpeg\]\|\[avconv\]'`
**Edit:**

Since you've requested `awk`,here's one with `awk`:

`youtube-dl --extract-audio --audio-quality 0 --newline --audio-format mp3 https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL1C815DB73EC2678E | awk '{if ($0~/^\[youtube\]/||/^\[ffmpeg\]/||/^\[avconv\]/||/^WARNING/) next;print}'`

Comment: The `[` and `]` should be escaped. With the `-E` option (extended regex option) you can avoid escaping `(`, `)` and `|` in the command: `grep -vE '\[(youtube|ffmpeg|avconv)\]'`. As for the "starting requirement", `^` needs to be prepended.

Comment: @Lekensteyn good point. I'll add that

Comment: @Serg not working. when executed it shows `>` and a blinking cursor. may be some syntax problem

Comment: @potholiday it was missing the single quote at the end. Fixed everything and added awk version. please review

Comment: `grep` script doesn’t show any difference from the original code, no change at all.  `awk` i tried like this `youtube-dl --extract-audio --audio-quality 0 --newline --audio-format mp3 https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL1C815DB73EC2678E | awk '{if(/[youtube]/||/[ffmpeg]/) $0="";print}'` it deletes all except `warning` lines

Comment: @potholiday you can add ||/WARNING/, too. like  `if(/[youtube]/||/ffmpeg/||/avconv/||/WARNING/)`

Comment: [ffmpeg] and WARNING are on separate lines, so you have to add that to if statement to delete that line

Comment: @Serg `awk` command prints only the warning lines it deletes all other the lines . eg it deletes [download]  line also

Comment: @potholiday What about `if ($0~/[youtube]/||/WARNING/||/[ffmpeg]/||/[avconv]/)` ? does that make difference ?

Comment: @potholiday OK, fixed both grep and awk versions, now should be working as it should. My attention to details isn't at its best. Let me know how this works

Comment: Now it seems to be working, however it leaves empty lines in place of the removed lines; change `$0=""` to `next` to fix this

Comment: @Serg `gerp` is working fine but `awk` has problem

Comment: @potholiday what exactly ?

Comment: @Serg  same problem `awk` only prints `WARNING` line.. any way your `grep` is working fine. But how to  delete `WARNING`  also.  I tried this `youtube-dl --extract-audio --audio-quality 0 --newline --audio-format mp3 https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL1C815DB73EC2678E | grep -vE '^\[(youtube|ffmpeg|avconv|WARNING)\]'` but still it prints WARNING line also

Comment: @potholiday in that code you posted, WARNING is inside brackets [ ].  Try `grep -vE '^\[(youtube|ffmpeg|avconv\]\|^WARNING` .

Comment: tried this `youtube-dl --extract-audio --audio-quality 0 --newline --audio-format mp3 https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL1C815DB73EC2678E | grep -vE '^\[(youtube|ffmpeg|avconv\]\|^WARNING'` but getting error

Answer (score 2):

Use `grep -v` as following:

```
youtube-dl --extract-audio --audio-quality 0 --newline --audio-format mp3 https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL1C815DB73EC2678E | grep -v '^[youtube]' | grep -v '^[ffmpeg]' | grep -v '^[avconv]'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Perl:

```
< inputfile perl -pe 's/^\[(youtube|ffmpeg|avconv)\].*$//' > outputfile
```

To parse the output of `youtube-dl --extract-audio --audio-quality 0 --newline --audio-format mp3 https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL1C815DB73EC2678E` directly, pipe its output to the command without redirecting the content of `inputfile`:

```
`youtube-dl --extract-audio --audio-quality 0 --newline --audio-format mp3 https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL1C815DB73EC2678E | perl -pe 's/^\[(youtube|ffmpeg|avconv)\].*$//' > outputfile`
```

- `< inputfile`: redirects the content of `inputfile` to `perl`'s `stdin`
- `> outputfile`: redirects the content of `perl`'s `stdout` to `outputfile`
- `-p`: places a `while (<>) { [...] }` loop around the script and prints each processed line
- `-e`: reads the script from the arguments

Perl script breakdown:

- `s`: asserts to perform a substitution
- `/`: starts the pattern
- `^`: matches the start of the line
- `\[`: matches a `[` character
- `(`: starts grouping the allowed strings
- `youtube`: matches a `youtube` string
- `|`: separates the second allowed string
- `ffmpeg`: matches a `ffmpeg` string
- `|`: separates the third allowed string
- `avconv`: matches a `avconv` string
- `)`: stops grouping the allowed strings
- `\]`: matches a `]` character
- `.*`: matches any number of any character
- `$`: matches the end of the line
- `/`: stops the pattern / starts the replacement string
- `/`: stops the replacement string

Comment: you might want to edit the command to include pipe from the OP's `youtube-dl` command. Others might not understand. Otherwise, I've tested it with an input file with text from OP's post,seems to work, hence +1

Comment: Thanks @Serg, I saw you updated yours as well so +1 on yours either

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar question with easy answer

```
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1493280/remove-lines-from-a-txt-file-that-start-with-a-special-string?noredirect=1#comment2616486_1493280
```