# Remove lines from a TXT file that start with a special string

Tags: 22.04, text-processing

Is it possible to remove all lines starting with // from a txt file?

Answer (score 0):

I used the command `sed`

```
sed -re '/^\s*\/\//d' myfile.txt > my_new_file.txt
```